# Set custom date for programmatically added woocommerce order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Set custom date for programmatically added woocommerce order
Hi guys, relatively simple question, I have this code that I would like to add the option to set the date for, I tried few options using - WC_Order::set_date_completed( $date ); and $date_modified->date("d/M/Y g:i:s") - but both failed. The code works by itself and adds an order to woocommerce, but they all get added for today's date. Also, the code is meant to add order as Completed but it comes as Pending Payment, if you can help with that too I would be grateful, cheers!

```
function create_vip_order() {

  global $woocommerce;

  $address = array(
      'first_name' => '111Joe',
      'last_name'  => 'Conlin',
      'company'    => 'Speed Society',
      'email'      => 'joe@testing.com',
      'phone'      => '760-555-1212',
      'address_1'  => '123 Main st.',
      'address_2'  => '104',
      'city'       => 'San Diego',
      'state'      => 'Ca',
      'postcode'   => '92121',
      'country'    => 'US'
  );

  // Now we create the order
  $order = wc_create_order();

  // The add_product() function below is located in /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract_wc_order.php
  $order->add_product( get_product( '129' ), 1 ); // This is an existing SIMPLE product
  $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
  //
  $order->calculate_totals();
  $order->update_status("Completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);

}

add_action( 'init', 'create_vip_order' );
```

Comment: Try adding `$order->save()` as the last line of the function